# Using observeEvent to observe two events and update output only when both of these two events changed

Tags: r, shiny, shiny-reactivity

I am trying to create a Shiny app to allow the user to **upload a file** and **select a method**. I would like the output to be returned/changed only when **both** the file is uploaded/changed and the method is selected/changed. In other words, I want the app to be silent when only one of the input variables is changed. Below I attached a demo code that will change the output when a file is modified/uploaded. I tried `req(file, method)`, but it does not work after the file is uploaded (e.g., upload/update another file). Any suggestions will be appreciated.

#### Code to create two CSV files for the shiny app demonstration.

```
df <- data.frame(obs = 1:11)
df2 <- data.frame(obs = 10:20)
write.csv(df, file = "uploaddf.csv", row.names = F)
write.csv(df2, file = "uploaddf2.csv", row.names = F)
```

#### Shiny app demo

```
library(shiny)
ui <- fluidPage(
  fluidRow(
    column(5, fileInput(inputId = 'file', 
                        label = 'Upload file',
                        multiple = FALSE)),
    column(5, selectInput(inputId = 'method', 
                          label = 'Select method',
                          list(`Method` = list("Method1", "Method2"))))
    ),
  br(),
  textOutput("printoutput")
  )
  
server <- function(input, output, session) {
  file <- reactive({
    req(input$file)
    filestr <- input$file
    file    <- read.csv(filestr$datapath, header = T)
    return(file)
  })
  
  method <- reactive({
    req(input$method)
    method <- input$method
    return(method)
  })
  
  observeEvent(file(), {
    op <- paste0(sum(file()), method())
    output$printoutput <- renderText({ op })
    })
  }

shinyApp(ui, server)
```

Comment: Is it an option for you to create a separate "run" button, so the user can control when to display new output?

Comment: Thanks for the reply @ismirsehregal Yes, I can add this kind of action button to do this, but I was wondering if there is an easy way to achieve this without adding this button.

Comment: In my eyes using a button is the clean way. Shiny is lazy - it will only fire new events when a selection actually was changed (which is also mentioned [here](https://www.rstudio.com/conference/2022/keynotes/past-future-shiny/) if you have some spare time). Please see [this related FR](https://github.com/rstudio/shiny/issues/3695). Accordingly if method 1 is to be used twice in a row you'll get no event, even if the user re-selects the option - this is done to save resources.

Comment: Good to know this. Will read these. @ismirsehregal

Answer (score 0):

I'd suggest using `bindEvent` along with an `actionButton` to wait for the user input:

```
df <- data.frame(obs = 1:11)
df2 <- data.frame(obs = 10:20)
write.csv(df, file = "uploaddf.csv", row.names = F)
write.csv(df2, file = "uploaddf2.csv", row.names = F)

library(shiny)
ui <- fluidPage(
  fluidRow(
    column(5, fileInput(inputId = 'file', 
                        label = 'Upload file',
                        multiple = FALSE)),
    column(5, selectInput(inputId = 'method', 
                          label = 'Select method',
                          list(`Method` = list("Method1", "Method2"))))
  ),
  fluidRow(
    column(5, actionButton(inputId = 'run', label = 'Render output', icon = icon("arrows-rotate")))
  ),
  br(),
  textOutput("printoutput")
)

server <- function(input, output, session) {
  file <- reactive({
    req(input$file)
    filestr <- input$file
    read.csv(filestr$datapath, header = T)
  })
  
  output$printoutput <- renderText({paste0(sum(file()), req(input$method))}) |> bindEvent(input$run)
}

shinyApp(ui, server)
```

PS: please try to avoid wrapping `renderXXX` functions in observers - they already are `reactive`.

Comment: Thanks! Actually, I have been wondering whether I should wrap rederXXX with observes. Can you share the potential drawbacks of doing this?